# Add Space Between Row Elements in React BootStrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React and react-bootstrap. I have a Row component and would like spacing between the top of the screen and also between the individual row elements. I am currently just editing its CSS but heard that it may be bad to mess with the CSS of frameworks?

```
const Styles = styled.div`
  .background {
    background: url(${backgroundImage}) no-repeat fixed bottom;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
  }

  #row {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
  }
`;

class Signup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Styles>
        <div className="background">
          <Container>
            <Row id="row" className="justify-content-md-center">
              <ExtraInfo />
              <SignupForm />
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </div>
      </Styles>
    );
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

[image]

Comment: it will be easier to help if you share a minimal, verifiable, complete example which replicates your issue

Answer (score 0):

*"Use the `gap` prop to add space between items."*
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/docs/layout/stack

```js
import Stack from 'react-bootstrap/Stack';


<Stack gap={3}>
    {/* your code */}
</Stack>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Form.Group in React-Bootstrap. It adds 15px padding on columns to separate the content of the columns.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not saying this is the best solution, but I have just created a CSS class that sets a margin attribute to 5px and then applied it to the Row element where I need it. This works for me, but I'm welcome to better answers.

For space at the top and bottom of the screen, what I have done is create a "spacer" component which I import and use to create space between elements.

I know what you mean about messing with the CSS though and this method might be a bit "hacky".

Example JSX:

```
      <>
        <p><strong>My Categories</strong></p>
        {
          catList.map((cat,i) => (
            <Row key={i} className="add-space">
              <Col><strong>Category {i+1}</strong></Col>
              <Col>{cat}</Col>
              <Col><Button onClick={() => removeCategory(cat)}>Remove</Button></Col>
            </Row>
          ))
        }
      </>
```

Example CSS:

```
.add-space {
  margin: 4px;
}
```

Example Spacer:

```
const Spacer = props => {
  return (
    <div style={{height:props.height}}></div>
  );
}

export default Spacer;
```

Use:

```
<Spacer height="1rem" />
```